# Linear hypothesis when regressor matrix singular? How do I do F-test?

Tags: multiple-regression

I have the following model
$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i,1} + \beta_2 x_{i,2}$
I know $\hat{\beta_0} $, $ \hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$, and also the $R_u$ and the covariance matrix of the model.

I now want to test this hypothesis:
$H_o: \beta_1 - \beta_2 = 1$ and $ \beta_1=-1$
Which boils down to:
$H_o: \beta_2 = 2$ and $ \beta_1=-1$
So the general form would be:
$R \hat{\beta}=r$ with $ R=[0,1,0;0,0,1]$ and $r=[-1;2]$.

I tried solving it with the F-test but didn't get far.
$F= \frac{(R \hat{\beta}-r)'[R(X'X)^{-1}R']^{-1}(R \hat{\beta}-r)/q}{\hat{\sigma}^2} $
I assume that
$X = [1,x_{i,1},x_{i,2}]$ but then $X$ would be singular and $X'X$ not invertable.

### EDIT:

I found some slides online, where it was implied that $\hat{\sigma}^2 X'X$ is the same as the covariance matrix. And then one could rewrite F:
$F= \frac{(R \hat{\beta}-r)'[R\hat{\sigma}^2(X'X)^{-1}R']^{-1}(R \hat{\beta}-r)}{q} $
If that's right and I can simply plug in the covariance matrix, then I know how to test this hypothesis. I'm still wondering why we're allowed to invert $X'X$ though...

#### end edit

What am I missing? How do I get the value for F, with these x's?
Or is this not feasible at all?

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers :)
Best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a sample $(y_i,X_i)$ with $i=1,...,N$ of independent and identical draws.

I think what you want to do is to define is the design matrix

$$ X = \begin{bmatrix} X_1^\top \\ \vdots \\ X_N^\top \end{bmatrix}$$

where each row

$$X_i^\top = (1,x_{i1}, x_{i2})$$

is the vector of covariate values for the i'th observational unit. This implies that

$$X^\top X = \sum_{i=1}^N X_iX_i^\top$$ where $X_iX_i^\top $ is the outer product matrix

$$X_iX_i^\top = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_{i1} & x_{i2} \\ 
x_{i1} & x_{i1}^2 & x_{i2}x_{i1} \\
x_{i2} & x_{i1}x_{i2} & x_{i2}^2\end{bmatrix}$$

if $X^\top X$ is not invertible for your sample $i=1,...,N$ then there is a problem, but the statement that $ (1,x_{i1}, x_{i2})$ is singular is hard to makes sense of because it is not a square matrix. Still the invertibility requirement is not on the individual outer product matrices but on the matrix of the sum of individual outer product matrices. The assumption is existence of $(X^\top X)^{-1} =\left( \sum_{i=1}^N X_iX_i^\top \right)^{-1} $.

Comment: This makes sense, I was confused about what the $i$ in $x_{i,1}$ actually signifies.  
Do I understand it correctly, to get $X'X$ it is necessary to have the actual data on the whole set of: $$X_1^\top ... X_N^\top$$ And if the number of observations is high, this is pretty much impossible to calculate by hand?

Comment: yes you need sample $i=1,...,N$ IID draws of $(y_i,X_i)$ or as you say actual data (but could be simulated).

Comment: It is not impossible to invert by hand a $3 \times 3$ matrix. The number of observations do not influence the dimensionality of $X^\top X$ matrix, this is determined by the number of variables you are observing for each individual which in your case is 3 ...as in 3 coordinates of vector $(1,x_{i1},x_{i2})$. But why do it by hand?!